# intellij Console Suppress Warnings in Terminal

Tags: intellij-idea, warnings

Is there a way to suppress these warnings so they don't show in Terminal window?

[image]

Comment: Is it Console output from Run/Debug Configuration? What Run Debug Configuration do you use?

Comment: this is from the terminal inside or Intelij.  I get same message once I package and run the JAR file.  I'm just hitting the Run button.... all this is very new to me... hope I explained it OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
Logger apacheLogger = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies");
apacheLogger.setLevel(Level.OFF);
```